# Unknown Generic return type in c# method

Tags: c#, generics, methods, types

I'm trying to create a measurement library in c# with compile-time checking of dimensions (length, time, ec.) Adding and subtracting are easy because they both used the same dimensions. However, when multiplying two scalars, the resulting Dimension (which I've used as the generic type), needs to be determined at run-time. Eg. Length x Length = Area, Area X Length = Volume, etc.

I'm only experimenting at this stage, but how would you resolve this problem (see below in method Times). The problem is that it can't convert from Area to Q in the return types.

```
public abstract class Dimension 
{ }

public class Length : Dimension 
{ }

public class Mass : Dimension 
{ }

public class Area : Dimension
{ }

public class Scalar<T> : Measure<T> where T : Dimension
{
    private float amount;

    public Scalar(float amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public static Scalar<T> operator +(Scalar<T> A, Scalar<T> B)
    {
        return new Scalar<T>(A.amount + B.amount);
    }

    public static Scalar<T> operator -(Scalar<T> A, Scalar<T> B)
    {            
        return new Scalar<T>(A.amount - B.amount);
    }

    public Scalar<Q> Times<S>(Scalar<S> that) 
        where Q : Dimension
        where S : Dimension 
    {
        return new Scalar<Area>(this.amount * that.amount);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "" + amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: the use case is like Scalar<Length> a = new Scalar<Length>(3); Scalar<Length> b = new Scalar<Length>(4); Scalar <Area> area = a*b; ???

Comment: This seems like overkill.  You could likely store the same information using [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) storing a float value and an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) value (said enum being the measurement types).

Comment: For compile time safety of units of measure, you need to make sure they are the same units (meters vs feet) rather than used to describe the same property (distance vs area).

Comment: this is only a subset of the whole thing. I plan to store the value in SI units (kg, m, s, etc.) So 1foot would be stored as 0.3048, so there's no problem adding and subtracting with different units. I'm just trying to figure out a way of having the program calculate the new dimension.

Comment: FYI there is already a nuget for this https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnitsNet

Answer (score 1):

To return a `Scalar<Area>` is a behavior that is not generic to all of `Scalar<T>`. For example, what if you were to multiply two `Scalar<Area>` instances? So you need somewhere to put that type-specific behavior. That means you have to subclass.

```
public class ScalarLength : Scalar<Length>
{
    public ScalarLength(float amount) : base(amount)
    {
    }
    public static Scalar<Area> operator *(ScalarLength lhs, ScalarLength rhs)
    {
        return new Scalar<Area>(lhs.amount * rhs.amount);
    }
}
```

Now you'll find this will work:

```
ScalarLength a = new ScalarLength(3);
ScalarLength b = new ScalarLength(4);
Scalar<Area> area = a * b;
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tBivym)

Another approach would be to define another generic class to represent the product of two scalars, e.g. a `Vector<T>`.

```
public class Vector<T> where T : Dimension
{
    public Vector(Scalar<T> lhs, Scalar<T> rhs)
    {
    }
}
```

Then use that as the return type, using the generic type argument:

```
public class Scalar<T> : Measure<T> where T : Dimension
{
    /* Snip */

    static public Vector<T> operator *(Scalar<T> lhs, Scalar<T> rhs)
    {
        return new Vector<T>(lhs, rhs);
    }
}
```

Now this will work:

```
Scalar<Length> a = new Scalar<Length>(3);
Scalar<Length> b = new Scalar<Length>(4);
Vector<Length> area = a * b;
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GuaRsb)

Comment: But the returned generic type should be Area, not Length. That's what I'm trying to get my head around.I was only doing this for interest sake, but maybe I'll look at that library mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Scalar<Q> Times<S,Q>(Scalar<S> that) 
    where Q : Dimension
    where S : Dimension 
{
```

Comment: How does this fix the OP's problem? It makes the signature legal, but the body still fails and it doesn't provide the semantics that the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do this with standard classes:

```
public abstract class Dimension
{
    public Dimension(double amount)
    {
        this.Amount = amount;
    }
    
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Length : Dimension
{
    public Length(double amount) : base(amount)
    { }
    
    public static Area operator *(Length a, Length b)
    {
        return new Area(a.Amount * b.Amount);
    }   
}

public class Area : Dimension
{
    public Area(double amount) : base(amount)
    { }
}
```